# Find the mode of a grouped query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column named **day_of_week** which consists of the numbers 1 to 7. I want to find the **mode** of this column for both casual and member categories. Like this in Spreadsheet.

[image]

I want to incorporate the mode query into my main query which is this.

```
SELECT
    member_casual,
    COUNT(rideable_type) AS total_bike,
FROM `case_study.bike_share.1`
GROUP BY member_casual
```

[image]

So that the final result will be like this in spreadsheet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try this
You need to rank the day_of_the week with most number or bike with row_number.

```html
WITH bike_share_v1 as 
(
    SELECT
        member_casual,
        day_of_week,
        COUNT(rideable_type) AS total_bike
    FROM case_study.bike_share.1
    GROUP BY 
 member_casual AND day_of_week
 )

SELECT * from 
(
SELECT 
    *,
    row_number() over(partition by member_casual order by total_bike desc) most_day_of_week
FROM
    bike_share_v1
)
WHERE most_day_of_week = 1
```

Comment: day_of_week with most frequent/repeated number = mode of the day_of_week for both categories casual&member.